# Read Heroku configuration variable from JavaScript

Tags: heroku

How do I read a configuration variable setup for a Heroku app.  For example:

[image]
From Azure I can use something like process.env.ALERT_ALLOW_TEST to read the environment variable setting.  However, how can I read this value from a Heroku environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed heroku does use process.env to retrieve values.  However, the type of the value (boolean) in this case was different between Azure and Heroku.  My boolean conversation routine wasn't taking that into account so it looked like it wasn't set but in fact it was being set.  I just wasn't converting it correctly.

Here is my toBoolean conversation routine that I modified from another Stackoverflow post.

```
function toBoolean(value)
{
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
        switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
            case "true": case "yes": case "1": return true;
            case "false": case "no": case "0": case null: return false;
            default: break;
        }
    }    
    return Boolean(value);
}
```